# file_get_contents error whilst using aviary

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, aviary

I have embedded aviary into my webpage and it is working fine but I am unable to use the file_get_contents command to grab the saved image.

the aviary code:

JS:

```
<!-- Load Feather code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://feather.aviary.com/js/feather.js"></script>

<!-- Instantiate Feather -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
var featherEditor = new Aviary.Feather({
    apiKey: '*********',
    apiVersion: 3,
    theme: 'light', // Check out our new 'light' and 'dark' themes!
    tools: 'crop,orientation,brightness,sharpness,redeye,effects,stickers,focus,contrast,whiten,warmth,colorsplash,enhance,saturation,blemish,draw,text,frames',
    appendTo: '',

    onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
        var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
        img.src = newURL;       
    },           

    onError: function(errorObj) {
        alert(errorObj.message);
    },

    postUrl: 'http://example.com/featherposturl'      
});

function launchEditor(id, src) {
    featherEditor.launch({
        image: id,
        url: src
    });
    return false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='injection_site'></div>

<img id='image1' src='photo.jpg' style="max-height:360px;" on/>

<p><input type='image' src='http://images.aviary.com/images/edit-photo.png' value='Edit photo' onclick="return launchEditor('image1', document.getElementById('image1').src);"/></p>
```

According to the aviary documentation I can grab the temp file that has been created on the aviary server but using this php code:

```
<?php

    $image_data = file_get_contents($_REQUEST['url']);

    file_put_contents("photo.jpg",$image_data);

?>
```

When I run this it errors out with this error

> [24-Sep-2013 12:14:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in......

Does anyone have any experience as to how I can grab the file that has been created on the aviary server and upload a copy to my server.

**UPDATE**
I notice a file called 'photo.jpg' is added to the server with a filesize of 0kb. I am assuming that this is from the `file_put_contents("photo.jpg",$image_data);` but the image data is blank as this is the error if the file_get_contents

Any ideas?

Comment: file_get_contents is the line above file_put_contents

Answer (score 0):

Please check that on your sever `allow_url_fopen = 0`

if it's value is 1 `file_get_contents` can't work

it that case you can use curl

Comment: according to my phpinfo file allow_url_fopen is set to 'on' in Local and Master

Comment: the file 'photo.jpg' is being uploaded to the server but with a filesize of 0kb, so something is working but I just dont fully understand the code

Answer (score 0):

Aviary posts back to a URL of your choice with a link to the file saved on their servers. So, you need to add a route on your server with the server-side code snippet above and make sure the postUrl you specify is the URL on your server that will call this code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this answer is probably a little late now, but I got around it this way. Its not the best way but it does work

In your javascript change this:

```
onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
        var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
        img.src = newURL;       
    },
```

to This:

```
onSave: function(imageID, newURL) {
        var img = document.getElementById(imageID);
        img.src = newURL;
        var old_image = $('#oldimage').val(); //this is a hidden field with the HTML LINK for the original image on your server
        $.ajax({
            url : 'PHP Processing page',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'JSON',
            data : {oldimage : old_image, newimage : img.src},
            success : function (json) {
                console.log(json);
            }
        }); 
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input id="oldimage" type="hidden" value="ORIGINAL IMAGE" />
<button class="button special fit" onclick="return launchEditor('image1', 'ORIGINAL IMAGE');">Edit This Image</button>
```

In the PHP processing page:

```
$default = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT");
define("SITEROOT",$default."/yoursite/");
define("SITEHTMLROOT", "http//www.yoursite.com/");

$oldimage = str_replace(SITEHTMLROOT, SITEROOT, $_POST['oldimage']);
$newimage = $_POST['newimage'];
copy($newimage, $oldimage);
```

As long as allow_url_fopen is set to on/1 this will work

You don't need to add the

> postUrl: 'http://example.com/featherposturl'

line to do it this way

As this post is very old, if you did find a good way of doing this would you share it?